# Simulate an "ontype" event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to simulate the Google Search effect that even with the search box not focused, the user can start typing and the input box will capture all keyboard strokes.

I have looked for an `ontype` event, but haven't found anything. I know that the `event` object in callbacks for events like `click` has keyboard information, but I don't think this is what I'm after.

Comment: how about `onkeypress` or `onkeyup`

Comment: Updated my answer. Apparently there is no need for catching character, changing target will do the magic.

Comment: Updated my answer again. :) I hope this time it's final.

Comment: You can accept your own answer too. But I appreciate if you accept mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the job:

```
 $(document).on('keydown', function() {
     $('input').focus();
 });
```

Comment: Yes this will work but since your input is part of `document` everytime you type something into input field this function will also run and will give focus to input which already has focus. There is one another way more elegant. I'm going to enhance my answer a little bit more.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
```

Javascript:

```
var googleLikeKeyCapture = {
    inputField : null,
    documentKeydown: function(event) {
        var inputField = googleLikeKeyCapture.inputField;
        if(event.target != inputField.get(0)) {
            event.target = inputField.get(0);
            inputField.focus();
        }
    },
    init: function() {
        googleLikeKeyCapture.inputField = $('#txtSearch');
        $(document).bind('keydown', googleLikeKeyCapture.documentKeydown);
        googleLikeKeyCapture.inputField
            .focus(function() {
                $(document).unbind('keydown');
            })
            .blur(function() {
                $(document).bind('keydown', googleLikeKeyCapture.documentKeydown);
            });
        googleLikeKeyCapture.init = function() {};
    }
};

$(googleLikeKeyCapture.init);
```

Also you can find jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/xWjhB/5/)

**EDIT :**

And now it's a [jQuery plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/xWjhB/7/). :) If keydown occures in a textarea or input field it doesn't capture keys, anything else goes to designated input field. If your selector matches more than one element it only uses the first element.

Usage: `$('#txtSearch').captureKeys();`

Comment: What is the line `googleLikeKeyCapture.init = function() {};` for? To avoid memory leak?

Comment: It's a habit. It prevents initializing the object more than once.

Answer (score 2):

The event you are after is [onkeypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent).

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery Text Change Event plugin:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event